# Https with certificate

Tags: java, https

I having trouble to call https URL with this code :

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(getRequestConfig())
        .setSSLSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getSystemSocketFactory())
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).setRoutePlanner(getRoutePlanner()).build()) {
...
...
```

I m getting :

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I already have add certificate in cacert of my jre and restart server but my client already say this message, what can i check? log? to see if client use my cacert file?

## EDIT1

during ssl communication i see this at the end :

```
Invalidated:  [Session-17, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
http-nio-8080-exec-10, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
http-nio-8080-exec-10, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
```

before all of this i can see my certificat in the log

Thanks

Comment: The PKIX path building failed means that with your HTTP Client you managed to reach the server you're trying to call, the server is sending back its own certificate and during the verification process on the client the validation fails since it is still not trusting it. You mentioned you already imported it inside the cacerts (truststore) but please make sure in case you have multiple java versions on that machine that you imported it into the right one. Check which exact jdk is your client using and recheck the cacerts and make sure the certificate you need to be trusted is there.

Comment: How are you running your application? Is it through an IDE? Through Maven? Gradle? A plugin-in? Plain java from a terminal?

Comment: @SofoGial its through tomcat

Comment: @IoanM : during start java_home is shown, i go in this path and add certificate with keytool to cacert in jre/lib/security/cacerts, see my edit #1